# Should I ask for a larger salary after expectation was met?

Tags: salary

Recently I quit the company I worked in for the last three years and have been on a job hunt for about two weeks. I've been taking interviews with two companies that contacted me almost at the same time and was asked my salary expectation, which I stated.

Currently, Company A works with clients in the US and I have been verbally offered a salary of almost 200% my expectation and a long list of benefits (Both of which I know are within the company's possibilities since I know a couple people who work there and earn more than that). Company B on the other hand, has made as of today, a formal offer that meets my original expectation.

Would it be proper to ask Company B to at least go up 50% on the original offer they made (and what I asked originally) to halfway meet Company's A offer? I know I'd be giving up 50%, but I'm willing to do that to honor the whole process and them making a formal offer first.

Comment: "I'm willing to do that to honor the whole process and them making a formal offer first." This part is completely insane to me. An offer is not binding! If anything, you should be upset at company A for forcing you to name your price first and then taking advantage of your ignorance regarding your real market rate. Company A can go to hell!

Answer (score 11):

> I'm willing to do that to honor the whole process and them making a
> formal offer first.

I'll never understand this line of thinking. You have **NO** obligation to either company. Not legally, morally, ethically, or otherwise. You are not a 12th century Japanese Samurai. There is no "code of honor" that you must obey. Stop thinking that you have some honor bound obligation to either party, because you don't.

Accept the offer that suits you best.

Comment: There is some "code of honour" that applies when you are hired and get paid: That you do the work you're hired for, and that you don't speak bad about them after you leave (unless they really deserve it, and then you're careful for legal reasons).

Answer (score 6):

> Would it be proper to ask Company B to at least go up 50% on the original offer they made (and what I asked originally) to halfway meet Company's A offer?

You should be very careful with this.

The company has made you a formal offer of exactly what you asked for.  You are now considering asking for 50% more.  Some companies might find your request to be insulting.  Insulting enough to remove you from consideration since they would:

- consider you to be too far apart from what they can possibly offer you
- consider you to not know exactly what you want

You need to ask yourself what changed that you would consider making such a request after you had already made a different request and received an offer that would have satisfied that original request.  If company A's "offer" is indeed verbal, then it really is not an offer.

Answer (score 3):

You should absolutely not consider taking a voluntarily  lower salary at A because of “the process” unless you already accepted the position.

If you have not you owe them nothing.  Get the formal offer from B, then if you think you’d like A better at an equal or slightly lower salary, just tell them “hey, I have another offer for $x, I like y’all but that’s a big differential” and see if they counter with something good - but good only means job quality plus compensation, not “honoring the process.”  Don’t be a corporate puppet. You owe you.

Answer (score 2):

You can always negotiate salary prior to accepting a job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: something has changed since you provided your salary expectations initially— you have two offers instead of zero. Ask them, "is this offer negotiable? I have another offer." If they say yes, ask for 50% more, but understand this may get the offer withdrawn. That's the risk. If they say no, don't negotiate.

Answer (score 1):

You have one formal offer in hand.

> Currently, Company A works with clients in the US and I have been
> verbally offered a salary of almost 200% my expectation and a long
> list of benefits (Both of which I know are within the company's
> possibilities since I know a couple people who work there and earn
> more than that).

They have given you a verbal offer. You have no way of knowing if this offer will ever arrive in written form. You have no idea what bad points it might contain. You are not bound by the verbal offer. Neither are they.

> Company B on the other hand, has made as of today, a formal offer that
> meets my original expectation.

Now this is closer to what you need. Of course they aren't locked in until you both agree to it. You have no obligation until that point.

> Would it be proper to ask Company B to at least go up 50% on the
> original offer they made (and what I asked originally) to halfway meet
> Company's A offer? I know I'd be giving up 50%, but I'm willing to do
> that to honor the whole process and them making a formal offer first.

You goal is to get company A to give you a written offer without conditions before you have to commit to company B's offer. Any negotiation with B risks you losing their offer. If you need money soon, then the impact of losing that offer could be very large.

An offer without conditions means that there are zero conditions. They don't need HR approval; the senior VP doesn't have to meet with you; they don't have to wait for the back ground check to be completed.

Until you get to that point keep looking. Keep interviewing. Try to get company A to complete their process.